# R: serialize objects to text file and back again

Tags: r, serialization

I have a process in R that creates a bunch of objects, serializes them, and puts them into plain text files. This seemed like a really good way to handle things since I am working with Hadoop and all output needs to stream through stdin and stdout.

The problem I am left with is how to read these objects out of the text file and back into R on my desktop machine. Here's a working example that illustrates the challenge:

Let's create a tmp file and write a single object into it. This object is just a vector:

```
outCon <- file("c:/tmp", "w")
mychars <- rawToChar(serialize(1:10, NULL, ascii=T))
cat(mychars, file=outCon)
close(outCon)
```

The mychars object looks like this:

```
> mychars
[1] "A\n2\n133633\n131840\n13\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
```

when written to the text file it looks like this:

```
A
2
133633
131840
13
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I'm probably overlooking something terribly obvious, but how do I read this file back into R and unserialize the object? When I try scan() or readLines() both want to treat the new line characters as record delimiters and I end up with a vector where each element is a row from the text file. What I really want is a text string with the whole contents of the file. Then I can unserialize the string.

Perl will read line breaks back into a string, but I can't figure out how to override the way R treats line breaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JD, we do that in the [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) package via `serialize()` to/from `raw`. That is nice as you can store serialized objects in SQL and other places. I would actually store this as RData as well which is way quicker to `load()` (no parsing!) and `save()`.

Or, if it has to be `RawToChar()` and ascii then use something like this (taken straight from `help(digest)` where we compare serialization of the file COPYING:

```
 # test 'length' parameter and file input
 fname <- file.path(R.home(),"COPYING")
 x <- readChar(fname, file.info(fname)$size) # read file
 for (alg in c("sha1", "md5", "crc32")) {
   # partial file
   h1 <- digest(x    , length=18000, algo=alg, serialize=FALSE)
   h2 <- digest(fname, length=18000, algo=alg, serialize=FALSE, file=TRUE)
   h3 <- digest( substr(x,1,18000) , algo=alg, serialize=FALSE)
   stopifnot( identical(h1,h2), identical(h1,h3) )
   # whole file
   h1 <- digest(x    , algo=alg, serialize=FALSE)
   h2 <- digest(fname, algo=alg, serialize=FALSE, file=TRUE)
   stopifnot( identical(h1,h2) )
 }
```

so with that your example becomes this:

```
R> outCon <- file("/tmp/jd.txt", "w")
R> mychars <- rawToChar(serialize(1:10, NULL, ascii=T))
R> cat(mychars, file=outCon); close(outCon)
R> fname <- "/tmp/jd.txt"
R> readChar(fname, file.info(fname)$size)
[1] "A\n2\n133633\n131840\n13\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
R> unserialize(charToRaw(readChar(fname, file.info(fname)$size)))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
R>
```

Comment: In retrospect I should have kept my objects as raw. I'll be sure and note that when I cobble together my lessons learned from using R on Hadoop. It looks like the piece I was missing was the readChar() functions. Thanks again Dirk!

Comment: Right. And I _completely_ forgot to plug our RProtoBuf package which of course also helps!  No Windows binary yet though as we have no MinGW-built version of the library suitable to link against with R.